# Total of numerical column in looped table (not total of query)

Tags: mysql, arrays, sum

Thank you in advance for detailed help and responses.

I've been stumped on this for weeks. Been researching online and cannot figure this out. Please help.

It's important to note - the column I am trying to get the total of is NOT stored in my sql database. SELECT SUM is not going to work for this. I also would prefer to not write the SUBTOTAL column into sql -- because if I would need to change the hours or the rate (if there was a clerical error), I would rather just change 1 field, than 2.

Here's what my table looks like, populated from sql query:
[table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIWqA.jpg)

Where the table says **TOTAL**, I need it to add up the column above it and populate the total.

Here's my code - it's long because I'm including everything in case you need it.

```
$staffquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kmis_transcribers WHERE transcriber_projectid = '$projectinvoiceid ' ORDER BY transcriber_calltime ASC");

$staffcount = mysqli_num_rows($staffquery);
for($i=0; $i<$staffcount; $i++) {
$staffarray = mysqli_fetch_array($staffquery);
$staffid = $staffarray['transcriber_id'];
$staffregid = $staffarray['transcriber_registryid'];
$staffposition = $staffarray['staff_position'];
$staffcalltime = $staffarray['transcriber_calltime'];
$staffrate = $staffarray['staff_rate'];
$staffhours = $staffarray['transcriber_hours'];
$staffovertime = $staffarray['transcriber_overtime'];


echo('<tr>

    <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px">$'.$staffrate.'</td>
    <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px">');

$invoicequery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kmis_invoices WHERE invoice_staffid='$staffid'");
  while ($invoicearray = mysqli_fetch_array($invoicequery)) {
           echo(''.$invoicearray['invoice_hours'].'');
}
   echo('</td>
         <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px">');

$invoicequery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kmis_invoices WHERE invoice_staffid='$staffid'");
  while ($invoicearray = mysqli_fetch_array($invoicequery)) {
           echo(''.$invoicearray['invoice_overtime'].'');
}
      echo('</td> 
        <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px">');

$invoicequery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kmis_invoices WHERE invoice_staffid='$staffid'");
  while ($invoicearray = mysqli_fetch_array($invoicequery)) {
           $invoicehours= $invoicearray['invoice_hours'];
           $invoiceovertime= $invoicearray['invoice_overtime'];

    $subtotal = ($invoicehours*$staffrate)+($invoiceovertime*$staffrate*1.5);
    $subtotalformat = number_format((float)$subtotal, 2, '.', '');

      echo('$'.$subtotalformat.'');
} 
   echo('</td>
   </tr>');
}
    echo('<tr>
        <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px"></td>
        <td align="right" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px" colspan="4"><b>TOTAL DUE:</b></td>
        <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
        </tr>
```

You can see that the formula I use to create the subtotal column uses four different queries -- from invoices and from staff. Some staff have different rates, so the subtotal is based on data that could be entirely different row to row.

I think the answer lies in **array_sum** and using an array to hold all of the $subtotal when they're populated but I'm completely stumped.

Thank you sincerely. Please let me know if you need me to clarify or help make this more precise.

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem.I have given an answer to your problems as it seems quite simple to me.Hoping to get a feedback from you soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read through your problem.The problem seems quite simple to me but your code is all messed up.What I understood was your **total** will be the sum of all the subtotal values,So

```
Total= 40$ + 108$ = 148$ //from your shown data in fig
```

Initialize a variable $total outside your for loop

```
  $total=0;
  for($i=0; $i<$staffcount; $i++) {
```

After you calculate your subtotal value, add this to your total as given below

```
$subtotal = ($invoicehours*$staffrate)+($invoiceovertime*$staffrate*1.5);
$total=$total + $subtotal; 
$subtotalformat = number_format((float)$subtotal, 2, '.', '');
```

Finally put the value of calculated $total in the result as

```
 echo('<tr>
        <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px"></td>
        <td align="right" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px" colspan="4"><b>TOTAL DUE:</b></td>
        <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:3px"><b>TOTAL : '.$total.'</b></td>
        </tr>
```

Your php code appears very lengthy and messed up,so I suggest you to try this query to make it short.

```
SELECT 
    t1.transcriber_id staff,
    t1.staff_position position,
    t1.staff_rate Rate,
    t2.invoice_hours hours,
    t2.invoice_overtime 'OT x 1.5',
    (t2.invoice_hours * t1.staff_rate) + (t2.invoice_overtime * t1.staff_rate * 1.5) subtotal
FROM
    kmis_transcribers t1
        JOIN
    kmis_invoices t2 ON (t1.transcriber_id = t2.invoice_staffid)
WHERE
    t1.transcriber_projectid=1 //$projectinvoiceid in your case
```

The above query will return the view that you want and your php code will be much simple now as now instead of four queries you need only one query.

Comment: Kiran, thank you for your help and suggestions. I'm still learning better and proper ways of making my code more precise, big thanks for your last suggestion of cleaning my code up.

Comment: I figured the answer to this was easy, I couldn't wrap my mind around it though.  -- I wanted you to know I saw your answer and I want to try to implement it today or tomorrow (work project taking my time this weekend) and will for sure let you know how it works for me. only question so far: do I need to initilize the total variable ($total=0 and so on) in the <td> with TOTAL: '.$total.' ?

Comment: @userK1400 Keep trying and never give up. $total holds the sum of all subtotals ,so it needs to be initialised above the loop where you are getting the subtotals.After the loop gets executed,$total now holds the sum of all the subtotals.This can now be used to display with TOTAL :.'$total.'.Try this so you will be learning better.If stuck we will help you :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I just tried the solution you gave and it works beautifully. I can't believe it was SO easy. haha. I really appreciate your kindness and help with this, sincerely.

Comment: Also - I am curious about 1 other problem I can't solve. I'm not sure if I can tag you in a new question that I ask, or if you have time, but I would love to see if you have advice -- in regards to not having a page refresh on a form submit. Sincere thanks again on the above question!

Comment: @userK1400 Put it as a new question and show your efforts.If not me there are thousands of Stackoverflow developers who can help you.Keep moving :).